# Почему при установке linux рядом c windows происходят неполадки?

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-mint, mbr

Всем доброго дня. Пытался установить ос `Linux Mint` на флешку, чтобы мог открывать её на любых компьютерах. Посмотрел ролики на `Youtube`. Видео говорили о том, что нужно использовать вторую вспомогательную флешку для установки на первую флешку. У меня не было второй вспомогательной флешки, поэтому я решил воспользоваться программой `UNetBootin`, которая смогла установить [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) (Lubuntu) рядом с [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) на другом компьютере. Но на моём она показывает ошибку:

> "Не удалось запустить Windows. Возможно, это проиошло из-за недавнего изменения конфигурации оборудования или программного обеспечения...".

В самой проблеме говорилось это:

```
"Файл: /ubnldr.mbr
Состояние :0xc000007b
Сведения: Не удалось загрузить приложение или операционную систему, так как необходимый файл отсутствует или содержит ошибки."
```

```
Версия UNetBootin: 702
Версия Linux Mint через сайт: 21
Версия Linux Mint через установщика образа UNetBootin: 20
Версия Windows: 10
```

Кроме `Linux Mint` никакой образ не устанавливал. Пробовал отключать `Secure Boot`, `Fast Boot`, и быстрого запуска. Ничего не помогало.